# Internet Explorer: expiration date for cookies doesn't work

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, reactjs, cookies, ecmascript-6

We are trying to set a cookie in order to use user auto login.

We are using an SPA with Reactjs + Redux + JavaScript (ES6),
To set the cookie we have created a component called `CookieHandler` which contains the set cookie function

```js
setCookie(token = '', expirationDate = '1970-01-01T00:00:00') {
  const expDay = new Date(expirationDate);

  document.cookie = 'userToken=' + token + '; expires=' + expDay.toUTCString() + '; path=/;';
}
```

We also made sure that it's called once, just when is needed.
This works for all browsers expect in Internet explorer.

**The problem is that IE sets the token in the current session but once we close the window and re-open it the cookie is gone, I also have tried to use `toGMTString` (which is deprecated) instead of `toUTCString` but still not working**

### Extra

We get the `userToken` and `expirationDate` from the back-end which its format is the same as the default value in the `setCookie` function

In all the other browsers works as expected even though we close the window.

Comment: Are you not setting an expiration date of 1970? (i.e in the past)

Comment: No, we are passing the date from backend which is 6 months duration, something like "2017-03-28T00:00:00" when we call the function

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12941511/internet-explorer-cookie-not-being-set-properly-using-javascript) I found some info that IE doesn't like "=" sign.
Maybe it's the problem?

> Don't use "=" signs in your cookie names.
>
> If you need them, use the single quotes to tell IE not to interpret it, but to accept it as a literal.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, It says that don't use double quotes instead use single quotes, as  you can see we are using single quotes. 
Furthermore, the problem isn't that the cookie is not set, the problem is that the cookie is gone once we close the window.

Comment: @JoseAPL I will look closer at that.